# Как решить проблему в ошибкой http://ogp.me/ns#image в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Сайт сверстан с помощью Wordpress. В нем установлен Yoast SEO. При проверке в вебмастере выдает ошибку:
[image: ошибка http://ogp.me/ns#image]

Я находила информацию для решения такого порядка:

[https://sheensay.ru/yoast#:~:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2,%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%2C](https://sheensay.ru/yoast#:%7E:text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2,%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%2C)

https://ontortuga.ru/oshibki-i-preduprezhdenija-validatora-mikrorazmetki-jandeks-vebmaster/#%d0%9e%d0%a8%d0%98%d0%91%d0%9a%d0%90-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-http-ogpmensimage-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be

Однако я не могу понять, где нужно добавить это изображение, поскольку интерфейс отличается. Я нашла настройки, однако здесь добавляется логотип и он в разметке отображается по-другому. Как исправить данную ошибку?